# How can I make sure vimeo (via iframe) shrinks to accommodate smaller column?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm mostly concerned with this page:
http://athomewhileaway.org/portraits.html

If I shrink the page so that it qualifies as a 'small' viewing device, the width of the iframe stays at 500, but I'd like this to be fluid.

UPDATE: Implementation based on the answer below:

```
  // Create a function which checks for the current window width and adapts all iframes
  function checkWidthAndAjustIframes() {
      var ifW;
      if ($( window ).width() < 500) {
        ifW = 400;
      }
      if ($( window ).width() < 400) {
        ifW = 300;
      }
      if ($( window ).width() >= 500) {
        ifW = 500;
      }
      $('iframe').attr('width', ifW);
      $('iframe').attr('height', .562*ifW);
  }

  // Call our check function on document ready
  $(document).ready(function(){
      checkWidthAndAjustIframes();
  });

  // Call our check function every time the window size changes
  $( window ).resize(function() {
      checkWidthAndAjustIframes();
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not absolutely sure but I think you will have problems to work with media queries in this case. And I also think you could work with JavaScript. So as it looks like you are using jQuery anyways you can try something like this:

```
// Create a function which checks for the current window width and adapts all iframes
function checkWidthAndAjustIframes() {
    if ($( window ).width() < 500) {
        $('iframe').attr('width', 400);
    }
    if ($( window ).width() < 400) {
        $('iframe').attr('width', 300);
    }
    if ($( window ).width() >= 500) {
        $('iframe').attr('width', 500);
    }
}

// Call our check function on document ready
$(document).ready(function(){
    checkWidthAndAjustIframes();
});

// Call our check function every time the window size changes
$( window ).resize(function() {
    checkWidthAndAjustIframes();
});
```

Note that you could also change the height in the same manner (to avoid black borders) or improve the check function a little by adding better conditions which suit your needs.

Comment: I was afraid of crossing streams with jQuery and bootstrap, but that's alright yeah? This is perfect, thank you!